# Click: NameError: name not defined

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm trying to use `click` to pass command-line arguments to a function but having difficulty.  I'm trying to pass two command-line arguments with this:

```
python script.py --first-a hi --second-a there
```

Here's my attempt:

```
import click
@click.command()
@click.option("--first-a")
@click.option("--second-a")
def main(first_a, second_a):
    print first_a, second_a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(first_a, first_a)
```

This fails with:

```
NameError: name 'first_a' is not defined
```

I thought this had to do with dashes vs. underscores but removing the dashes and underscores (just using `firsta` and `seconda`) also fails with the same issue.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `main()` either without any arguments, or with a list of parameters as would normally be found in `sys.argv`.

#### Code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option("--first-a")
@click.option("--second-a")
def main(first_a, second_a):
    print(first_a, second_a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test code
    import sys
    sys.argv[1:] = ['--first-a', 'hi', '--second-a', 'there']

    # actual call to click command
    main()
```

#### Results:

```
hi there
```